# Show only part of a video stimulus in psychopy

Tags: video, playback, psychopy

Is it possible to have Psychopy's [`MovieStim`](http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/moviestim.html#psychopy.visual.MovieStim) play only a certain *spatial* percentage of a movie file?

I would like to be able to show 0-25% of the x-size of a stimulus, then 25-41% etc. It is not feasible for me to manually crop the videos, because I need to control the crop coordinates at runtime.

I am currently using [this code](https://github.com/TheChymera/behaviopy/blob/master/behaviopy/event_tracking.py), and I was hoping to get the effect I want with the `MovieStim.size` attribute somehow, but that invariably controls the size of the entire movie.

Comment: You will get quicker answers by posting your question on psychopy's support forum: discourse.psychopy.org. We are stopping our presence on StackOverflow, but you are of course welcome to wait and see if answers tick in here!

Comment: Yes, this should be possible using the aperture stimulus http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/aperture.html (which allows partial drawing of other stimuli). As Jonas notes, bring this up at http://discourse.psychopy.org for more support if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished via an Apperture object:

```
aperture = visual.Aperture(win, size=0.2, pos=(0, 0), ori=0, nVert=120, shape='square', inverted=False, units="norm", name=None, autoLog=None)
```

This can be added at any point in the code before the stimulus is drawn.